# Most efficient was to reuse classes across iOS Projects

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, static-libraries, code-reuse

I have created a number of re-usable classes that I use across xcode projects, for example:
Utility
EmailController
MarketingController
FlashLightController
etc

I had been simply copying these class files from and back into a central repository, but now I have a number of apps it is all getting a little confusing from a config management point of view.  So I was looking for an alternative.

I started investigating Static Libraries but they seem to be quite a lot of more effort for simply re-using code (e.g. different libs for device vs simulator, still having to have copies of .h files, etc).

Does anyone know of a decent alternative for quick and easy code reuse?

Thanks, Charlie

Comment: The ideal solution would be a dynamic library, too bad iOS doesn't allow their use (by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code files into a project without actually copying them into the project. In other words, just keep the class files in a completely separate location. Import them into many projects, but uncheck the option to copy them in. The projects will still refer to them successfully. Now a change made in the class files will propagate to every project that uses them.

Also, consider whether workspaces will help you.

In my view, almost anything is better than making a library or framework!

Comment: Thanks Matt... and agree I did not get on well with static libraries... seemed way to much effort for what is a simple requirement. This is the simplicity I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: referencing will get you in trouble soon enough... there is no 'fixed version of a class' you can assign to a project... proj a will have file f, project b will have f. now if b needs to modify f, it will change project a .. BAD idea (even it it seems to work out at first, it goes usually wrong later)

Comment: + the paths might *likely) break sooner than later  (when you move to another computer or move dirs or whatever)

Comment: The path problem isn't really a problem; most repositories — including git — allow you to reference submodules, which means the referenced code is a separate repository on the server but git will handle putting it onto disk as an inherent part of your final product's project and keeping it linked to the latest remote version.

Comment: Tommy/Daij-Djan - thanks for the comments. Discussed with one of our senior devs who agreed aswell. But also agreed libraries are a bit overkill for my simple requirements. He suggested just copying files and keeping a central repo (ideally in git). Will go with that option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Static libraries would probably be your best bet, as I have used them and have found them to be pretty easy to use. (I haven't had to use different libraries for device or simulator, mine works on them all). Having the header isn't that annoying, and static libraries are really the only way (outside of dynamic libraries, which are banned by apple) other than copying the files to reuse code.